# Stepped error handling

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am running the following :-

```
    private void ConvertFile()

    {
        PrepElec1();
        MakeElec2();
        MakeElec3();
        MakeElec4();
        MakeElecMerged();
        SetDataSet.SetData(DtSet);
        btnConvert.Enabled = false;
        btnReport.Visible = true;
    }
```

How can I impliment try/catch,so that if one of these fails...

```
        PrepElec1();
        MakeElec2();
        MakeElec3();
        MakeElec4();
        MakeElecMerged();
```

...I get a messagebox showing at which step it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the Exception's stack trace do the work for you.

```
private void ConvertFile()
{
    try
    {
        PrepElec1();
        MakeElec2();
        MakeElec3();
        MakeElec4();
        MakeElecMerged();
        SetDataSet.SetData(DtSet);
        btnConvert.Enabled = false;
        btnReport.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var trace = e.StackTrace;

        // format trace however you like

        MessageBox.Show(this, trace, "Error");
    }
}
```